# What do you call a person who always has a pleasant smile on his face?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, british-english

What do you call a person who always has a pleasant smile on his face. Is there anything better than calling him a "Pleasing personality"?

Comment: [Cheerful](http://thesaurus.com/browse/cheerful?s=t), [naïve](http://thesaurus.com/browse/gullible?s=t), [pleasant](http://thesaurus.com/browse/pleasant?s=t), [half-witted](http://thesaurus.com/browse/cretinous?s=t). Surely this is GR, but why in the world is it tagged Britspeak?

Comment: Blithesome, genial, convivial.

Comment: A flight attendant?

Comment: It depends. As Shakespeare said, one can smile and smile and still be a villain.

Comment: 'A smug git' is often appropriate.

Comment: A _ray of sunshine_.

Comment: "Not paying attention."

Comment: @Jay Actually, Shakespeare didn't include the word _still_ in his phrase but I like the saying better with the word _still_ (or even better, _yet_) in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this question really should have more context; it depends on whether or not the smile is genuine (and, if it is, it depends on the source of that person's happiness.)

If the smile is phony (that is, the person always smiles, but in reality, they are very bitter on the inside), then I'd call that person ***plastic***, or [***saccharine***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/saccharine).

On the other hand, if the smile is a sign of the person's pleasant nature, there several words that could be used to describe the person, depending on that person's source of joy and contentment, including: ***joyful, pleasant, happy, cheerful,*** and ***jocular***.

> Is there anything better than calling him a "Pleasing personality"?

One thing is certain, however, I would not call that person a "pleasing personality." You might say, *"He **has** a pleasant personality,"* but a pleasant personality is something you *have*, not something you *are*.  Moreover, a "pleasing personality" could be misinterpreted to mean that this person is predisposed to pleasing other people, rather than that this person is constantly smiling.

Comment: I used to work with someone with a genuine, cheerful personality.  We found the word "happy camper" fitting his personality.

Answer (score 3):

I think  of such people as affable

Comment: I think of such people as folks who don't listen to the news.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

> *Happy-go-lucky
>
>   Cock-eyed optimist
>
>   Hail fellow well met
>
>   Devil-may-care
>
>   Slap-happy
>
>   Carefree
>
>   Lighthearted
>
>   Blithe
>
>   Village idiot*

Answer (score 1):

I would use *amiable*, which means, per *Webster's Collegiate Thesaurus* (1988), "of a generally agreeable nature especially in social interaction". Other options are *good-humored*, *good-tempered*, *good-natured*, and (rather rare these days) *complaisant*. All of the synonyms for *amiable* I've listed come from that same thesaurus.

Answer (score 0):

*Jocular*, *in a jocky way*, *congenial*, *in a sociable way*.

Comment: In a [_jocky_](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/spellcheck/british/?q=jocky) way? What does that mean?

Comment: deeply sorry , wrong punctuation ...Jocular:in a jocky way, congenial:in a sociable way.

Comment: I don't believe "jocky" is a word - that's my point.

Comment: @J.R. it is a word. Seems like archaic variant of _jockey_, a horse rider. What they meant is, obviously _jokey_ or _joky_ (alternative spelling).

Comment: @theUg: Yes, obviously, as you said. (I wasn't really confused; my goal was to exhort a new user to be more careful, and fix their errors. Had a more established user made the same mistake, I probably would have just fixed it with an edit.)

Answer (score 0):

-Daydreamer

-The writer, Mr. Doe, always had a pleasant smile on his face because he was always daydreaming about new characters, times and places where he could set his stories.