# Word for something which is “on the side” or which manifests “at the edge”?

Tags: single-word-requests

I will use a smile as an example (though the word **should work in general for something which is “at the edge”**).

So what I want is an adjective for a half-smile which would fit in, say, the following sentence.

> … a smile; subtle and ______ .

Here are some possibilities I looked at but didn't satisfy my description:

1. *extreme:* Literally means something at the extremity or end, but it is not usually used in the physical sense so it would convey a different meaning.
2. *quasi*: Doesn’t describe the location of the smile, also cannot stand alone as an adjective.
3. *crooked*: Fits the sentence I provided but doesn’t mean “at the edge”.
4. *lopsided*: Like *crooked*.
5. *uneven*: Same problem.

I already checked out [A word that refers to a "half-smile"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117586/a-word-that-refers-to-a-half-smile), but the answers either provide a noun, or an adjective which doesn’t have the meaning of “at the edge”.

Comment: You want ***liminal***: *1. of or at the limen, or threshold 2.  at a boundary or transitional point between two conditions, stages in a process, ways of life, etc.*. In psychology, a sensation which is just barely perceptible is *liminal*. In modern literature, airports, train stations, long car rides, all the dull a dreary places one spends time *between* A and B, only functioning to get you from A to B, with no other meaning in life, are *liminal spaces*.

Comment: @DanBron Nope, liminal is not what I'm looking for since it refers to a process. I need something on the line of 'lateral' but meaning "at the edge"

Comment: It is not only for a process, as I describe in more derail in the above comment. It is any threshold. The doorjamb between you home and the outside is liminal, for example (that's the ultimate origin of the word, *limen*), as is the seashore or coast (though that has a more specialized term, *littoral*). I understand what you need, so far *liminal* is my best recommendation.

Comment: @DanBron Thanks for the explanation, however liminal refers to a transition or threshold, what I need is an adjective for a physical location, maybe on the lines of 'marginal' or 'peripheral'

Comment: I have explained to you twice now that *liminal* applies to physical locations and given you several compelling examples. I do not know why it is unclear that *liminal* defines "places just at the edge".  But if you don't like it, you don't like it.  So maybe you'll prefer something from [Wikipedia's article on *Anatomical terms of location*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatomical_terms_of_location), such as *lateral* (on the side, like your left side) or *distal* (far away from the main body of the structure). Both those terms have their own drawbacks, but maybe you can make them work.

Comment: @DanBron Liminal has connotations beyond simply meaning physically at the edge or extremity. Liminality is a concept. In anthropology the word is used when referring to rites of passage because it conveys a transition point. A "liminal" smile would be one which a person gives when they realize that they are entering a new stage in life.

Comment: Your first two sentences are correct. Your last sentence is not correct. A *liminal* smile can happen at any time at all, for any reason. It's just perceptible. Either visually, to the person seeing it, because it's subtle, not full-blown, just at the edge of the mouth; it has started there, as all smiles do, but progressed no further, just as you describe in your sentence. Or mentally, to the one doing the smiling, who feels the first feather of joy, or humor, or snarky condescension, in their hearts. It's a subtle signal betraying a subtle emotion. Think Mona Lisa.

Comment: But I'm not here to convince you. You asked for a word and I've given you the word. You can use it or not. You can try other, more anatomical or clinical terms, like *lateral* or *distal* or anything else. But whether you do or don't use *liminal*, it doesn't change the meaning of the word, and that meaning is just how I've described it.

Comment: @DanBron It's a pretty interesting discussion about the meaning of the word. Maybe my basic background in anthropology makes me perceive the word as having a lot more weight than it has to the average person, which is why I cannot put my head around using the word casually like you did in your last example.

Comment: It's not so much a casual usage as literary. It's a well-established usage for "things at the edge, or things in between", usually with a metaphorical, often wistful, sometimes mystical, bent. But it does *literally* mean a physical threshold, border, edge. It comes to us from the Latin [*limen*: "threshold, cross-piece, sill"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Liminal), as does *limit* as in the *outer limits* of something - say, a mouth.

Comment: @DanBron I've never seen liminal used in a literal sense then, but I'll take your word for it. Can you post it as well as the explanation "A liminal smile can happen... Mona Lisa" as an answer for me to accept it?

Comment: If you like. I rarely post answers any longer. But I've already written most of it in the comments by this point. I'll do it later today. And I'll leave you with this quote from a story in the anthology [The Oxford Book of American Short Stories](https://books.google.com/books?id=mrgN3iexFn8C&pg=PA744&lpg=PA744&source=bl&ots=t9cDNp_qFq&sig=VkN6GLZWhpjF_tU9gK_XseaTGvc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicqNmd6oDUAhVHOiYKHVwRAjEQ6AEIKjAF#v=onepage&f=false): *Susan Certain ... is giving him a look he's never seen before. The **liminal smile**, the coy arch of the eyebrows ... "How may I persuade you?"*.

Comment: @DanBron The quote is perfect. Yeah I think it's better to post it as an answer so that future visitors would know that the question got answered.

Comment: How would you feel if I suggested we close this question as a dupe of the one you found, and then I lost my answer there? We don't have to, I don't like my questions closed either, but I do kinda feel that the questions are he same but no one has posted the best answer on that other question. It would also be more of a fair fight between my answer and those others, being a latecomer notwithstanding.

Comment: @DanBron My question is by no means a duplicate. The author of the other question was clearly searching for a noun which is why they accepted "smirk" as the best answer. Also I am looking for a word which means "at the edge" and a smile just happened to be an example I used.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll answer here.

Comment: *Peripheral* is another option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > **liminal**: *1. of or at the limen, or threshold 2. at a boundary or transitional point between two conditions.*
>
> The word liminal can refer to any threshold, including a physical one. The doorjamb between your home and the outside is liminal, for example (that's the ultimate origin of the word, *limen*), as is the seashore or coast (though that has a more specialized term, *littoral*).
>
> A *liminal* smile can happen at any time at all, for any reason. It's just perceptible. Either visually, to the person seeing it, because it's subtle, not full-blown, just at the edge of the mouth; it has started there, as all smiles do, but progressed no further, just as you describe in your sentence. Or mentally, to the one doing the smiling, who feels the first feather of joy, or humor, or snarky condescension, in their hearts. It's a subtle signal betraying a subtle emotion.
>
> An example can be found in a story in the anthology [The Oxford Book of American Short Stories](https://books.google.com.cy/books?id=mrgN3iexFn8C&pg=PA744&lpg=PA744&source=bl&ots=t9cDNp_qFq&sig=VkN6GLZWhpjF_tU9gK_XseaTGvc&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false): *"Susan Certaine ... is giving him a look he hasn't seen before. The liminal smile, the coy arch of the eyebrows ..."*

Full credit goes to Dan Bron for providing the answer in the form of comments.

Answer derived from his comments based on SE policy [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat).

Answer (score -1):

"Liminal" isn't a very common word. If you want it to be familiar to a general audience, I recommend a more common synonym. For instance, there's "faint" or "slight", or the two words phrase "barely perceptible".

Comment: But these words do not mean "at the edge".